# Почему в phpstorm вместо комментирования на сочетание CTRL + / сворачивается код и ставится три точки?

Tags: phpstorm

Как исправить, подскажите.
Пробовал сбрасывать хоткеи и заного делал CTRL+/ один фиг сворачивает код, а не комментирует

Comment: Может раскладка клавиатуры не та?

Comment: попробуйте переключиться сперва на английскую раскладку

Answer (score 1):

Язык клавиатуры должен быть Eng или Ctrl + Num / сработает точно.

Comment: Мне тоже этот способ помог